# Hibernate Search not returning results on newly created entities

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I am using Hibernate Search in a Multi-tenant Hibernate application. As per [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.9/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-multi-tenancy) link, I expect this to work out of the box, but the search results do not seem to return newly-created entities.

Here are my mappings:

```java
@Entity
@Indexed
public class ItemEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Field
    private String name;

    @Field
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderBy("versionNo DESC, lastSaveDate DESC")
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private List<ItemVersionEntity> versions;

    ...
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class ItemVersionEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Field
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "version", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private List<ItemEdgeEntity> edges;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "version", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private List<ItemNodeEntity> nodes;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
    @ContainedIn
    private ItemEntity item;
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class ItemEdgeEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Field
    private String text;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "version_id")
    @ContainedIn
    private ItemVersionEntity version;
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class ItemNodeEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Field
    private String text;

    @Field
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "version_id")
    @ContainedIn
    private ItemVersionEntity version;
}
```

After adding a `ItemNodeEntity` called `foobar`, I am using [this](https://github.com/flaxsearch/marple) tool to see that it appears in the index (although I don't quite understand the structure of the index, and not sure if the different Segments are a problem):
[Marple image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7IUC.png)
[Luke image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKvQH.png)

And this is some of the query code that returns 0 results:

```java
SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
Session session = sessionFactory.withOptions().tenantIdentifier(tenantIdResolver.resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier()).openSession();
FullTextSession fullTextEM = Search.getFullTextSession(session);

QueryBuilder itemQB = fullTextEM.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(ItemEntity.class).get();

Query mq = itemQB
                .keyword()
                .onField("versions.nodes.text")
                .matching("foobar")
                .createQuery();

FullTextQuery ft = fullTextEM.createFullTextQuery(mq, ItemEntity.class);
List<Object> result = ft.getResultList();
```

Note that if I reindex the entire database, the above search works:

```java
FullTextSession fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
```

Hibernate: 5.2.13
Hibernate Search: 5.9.3

### Edit:

It seems after saving a `ItemVersionEntity`, the `__HSearch_TenantId` field gets removed from the Lucene document:
[Luke document image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTmkf.png)

This is the way Multi-tenancy is implemented (basically following [this](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-hibernate-multitenancy-implementation) guide):

```java
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JpaProperties jpaProperties;

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
                                                                       MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl,
                                                                       CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl) {

        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.putAll(jpaProperties.getHibernateProperties(new HibernateSettings()));

        properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.SCHEMA);
        properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProviderImpl);
        properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, currentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan(...);
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments of my other answer, this is a bug that occurs only when using multitenancy in very specific cases (2 or more levels of `@IndexedEmbedded`, apparently): https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3647

To work around the bug, the best you can do is to reindex explicitly just after the merge:

```
Search.getFullTextSession(s).index(updatedVersion.getItem());
```

If you cannot realistically know in advance which entities are going to need to be reindex, there is potentially a hack you can use... but it's really a hack: be sure to test it properly. The idea is to ask Hibernate Search to perform an operation that won't change anything, but will have the side effect of initializing some internal structures properly.
After you started your transaction, just trigger a purge operation that you're absolutely sure won't have any effect, by using an entity ID that you're absolutely sure does not match any entity:

```
Search.getFullTextSession(s).purge(ItemEntity.class, -1);
```

Then the internal structure for that entity type will be initialized properly, and @ContainedIn processing will work fine for the rest of the transaction.
If you have other indexed types, you will have to do the same for each type that could potentially be affected by your transaction.

Note the purge operation will still be executed, it's just that it won't have any effect since the ID does not match anything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems youre mapping is lacking an association from `ItemVersionEntity` to `ItemEntity`. You need this association, along with an `@ContainedIn` annotation, in order for Hibernate Search to be able to retrieve the relevant `ItemEntity` instance and reindex it whenever the `ItemVersionEntity` (or the embedded nodes) changes.

Basically, if you want automatic reindexing to work properly, whenever you have an entity A with an `@IndexedEmbedded` annotation on an association to type B, you need entity B to declare the inverse side of that association to type A, and a `@ContainedIn` annotation on that inverse association.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - the `@ContainedIn` does exists on the `ItemVersionEntity` - I had just removed it by mistake when removing the irrelevant properties. I've updated the question.

Comment: Do you also make sure to update *both* sides of  associations when you add a node? That's another potential pitfall.

Comment: Hmm, the associations are updated both ways, but after you mentioned it, it could have something to do with the fact that the `ItemVersionEntity` is saved by using `session.merge(version)` - where the `nodes` list is a mix of existing (with IDs) and new (without IDs) objects - all of them have the `version` back reference set, though. The weird part is that the `foobar` Term looks like is already inside the index (installed Luke as well as the other app I mentioned in the question and it appears in Luke as well)

Comment: I just noticed you're using multi-tenancy. Does the `__HSearch_TenantId` field in the index have the value you expect?

Comment: Inspecting in Luke, I can see that as soon as I save the `ItemVersionEntity`, there is no longer a `__HSearch_TenantId` field at all on the Lucene document. So saving somehow removes the `__HSearch_TenantId` field. I will update the question with the way the multi-tenant properties are set, the problem must be somewhere there?

Comment: The missing tenant ID is definitely the reason you're not finding the entity. Now the most likely explanation is that the ORM session you created (the one you call `.merge` on) does not have a tenant ID; it should have one. If your ORM sessions, all of your ORM sessions, do have a tenant ID, then there is a bug, and if you create a ticket on [our JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HSEARCH) with a reproducer, we can try and fix it. The missing tenant ID on the session is more likely, though.

Comment: Both of these calls before the `.merge` method return the correct tenant ID:  
`((AbstractSharedSessionContract) session).tenantIdentifier;` . 
`session.doWork(con -> { String s = con.getSchema(); });` . 
I will try and create a small reproducible example if I can

Comment: Also, this only seems to happen when the `nodes` of the `ItemVersionEntity` passed to `.merge` contains a new object (without an ID, but again, the back-reference is set). Removing a `node` (or calling `.merge` a second time without changes) actually restores the searchability of the `ItemEnitty`

Comment: I've created a Jira ticket with a test case: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-3647